# Density distributions in R

Tags: r

An assignment has tasked us with creating a series of variables: normal1, normal2, normal3, chiSquared1 and 2, t, and F. They are defined as follows:

```
library(tibble)
Normal.Frame <- data_frame(normal1 = rnorm(5000, 0, 1), 
    normal2 = rnorm(5000, 0, 1), 
    normal3 = rnorm(5000, 0, 1), 
    chiSquared1 = normal1^2, 
    chiSquared2 = normal2^2, 
    F = sum(chiSquared1/chiSquared2), 
    t = sum(normal3/sqrt(chiSquared1 )))
```

We then have to make histograms of the distributions for normal1, chiSquared1 and 2, t, and F, which is simple enough for normal1 and the chiSquared variables, but when I try to plot F and t, the plot space is blank.

Our lecturer recommended limiting the range of F to 0-10, and t to -5 to 5. To do this, I use:

```
HistT <- hist(Normal.Frame$t, xlim = c(-5, 5))

HistF <- hist(Normal.Frame$F, xlim = c(0, 10))
```

Like I mentioned, this yields blank plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your t and F are defined as sums; they will be single values. If those values are outside your range, the histogram will be empty. If you remove the sum() function you should get the desired results.